# overflow hidden and absolute position

Tags: html, css

In the following markup, I want to set the position of inner outside the `.wrap` to get the following results:

[image]

However the problem is that the `.wrap` has `overflow: hidden` which is generated automatically and cannot be changed. Is there any other way to achieve the same result without changing the css of the .wrap?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    overflow: hidden; /* problem */
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;   
}

.inner{
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -50px;
    top: 0;
    background: green;
    z-index: 3;        
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/bAGTg/

Comment: Are you able to add any HTML after the `<div class="wrap">`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why overflow: hidden; can't be changed, or is it because you don't have control over it?

Comment: Yes. I can change anything inside the wrap.

Comment: @Mat-visual I do not have control over the .wrap. I can only add content inside.

Comment: Why cant you just override the `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: You can override .wrap from css with !important. you can control it. It's not possible to display inside div if outer div is overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just on `.wrap` add `overflow:visible !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with  your code..

```
.wrap{
    overflow: visible;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;   
}
```

Good Luck Bro..